# How to read from a given data file?

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm in University studying computer science.

This is actually my first big assignment but they haven't taught us how to do the main bits in it yet.

What I need help with is that my program has to take its information from a .dat source file and use the information within that .dat file to perform its grade calculations etc.
They have not taught us this yet (and i dont think they will before the assignment hand in date), how to take the information from this source file!

The **.dat file format** contains a string of single characters seperated by whitespace:

> A B C A D F E

I would greatly appreciate any assistance that anyone could provide me in this area!

Comment: What have you learned in your class?

Comment: Okay, I know you're enthused, but there isn't much to go on at this point.  What's the file format of the .dat file?  CSV?  Binary serialized data?  XML?

Comment: Apart from being a pure homework question, you have not provided us any useful information that we could use to assist.

Comment: If it's the first big assignment in a CS course, I would expect the .dat file to be simple, probably tab delimited data with names and grades or something like that. Nothing too complicated.

Comment: Whow. First larage assignment. That should be the level before they approove you to a CS course.

Comment: Come on guys... give the guy a break. Don't act like you would not have used SO if it had existed when you were at University :P

Comment: @cameron: Please follow [general](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) question [guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread71507.html) (not my work):

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("MyFile.dat");
string strAllFile = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\n\r", "\n");
string[] arrLines = strAllFile.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
textBox1.Text = arrLines[0];
textBox2.Text = arrLines[2];
```

That is reading line one from the .dat file and putting it into textbox1, and then reading line 3 and putting that in textbox2 using array.

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("MyFile.dat");
writer.WriteLine("Hello");
writer.WriteLine("World");
```

That is writing hello and world to two lines in a .dat file.

Comment: alright thanks guys this was a big help... 
i started coding my program with this and also some things iv seen online!... great stuff guys thanks a million!.. ill be back with some more issues im sure!..ill do my research online first tho!
thanks

regards

Comment: @cameron: don't forget to mark the answer you found most helpful as accepted (under the score for each answer is a tick that chan be selected)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your file is going to be plain text, and each record is a single row... then you can simply do this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("grades.dat");

foreach(var line in lines)
{
    //Do some parsing here
}
```

How you parse your lines will be heavily dependent on your format, of which you have not provided.

### UPDATE:

If the information is all going to be contained in a single line like that, then it is even easier. I won't give you the solution, but there are a couple of methods you should read up on:

[`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)

[`String.ToCharArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx)

[`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx)

[`foreach,in`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[`switch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

That should be pretty much all you need to get the job done. Happy reading :)

Comment: i do apologise to all!.. the information is very basic and only contain type Char's, basically they are shown as below:
A
B
C
G
A

etc

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any info about the file format I can only offer basic stuff.

brief guide to opening a file
http://www.csharp-examples.net/filestream-open-file/

brief guide to reading a file
http://www.csharp-examples.net/filestream-read-file/

To be frank you'll find google is your friend for this, one of the most important things you'll learn in programming is how to use google to find the information you need about features of a language that are alien to you.

I grabbed these two tutorials in seconds searching for "c# open file", its an essential first step as while this is nicer than most places, people online tend to respond negatively when you haven't first done basic research

Answer (score 0):

The first step you should take is to write out the steps your programme will take.

e.g.

1. start running
2. load the dat file
3. do the calculations
4. use the results of the calculations
5. stop running

Each of those tasks could be broken down into smaller tasks, so you should do that too, until you're at a point where you can write some code.

Not knowing anything about your file format, the calculations that need to be done, or what you intend to do with the results of your calculations means that I can't really explain any more.

Some basics:

**Loading a file**

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("filename.dat"))
{
    //use your file here
    //e.g
    var lines = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new [] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None);
    //will read all of the lines in your file into an string[]
}
```

**Simple calculations**

```
using System.Linq
//other code
//given that numbers is IEnumerable<double>
double average = numbers.Average()
double sum = numbers.Aggregate((tot, n) => tot+n);
double sumOfSquares = numbers.Select(n => n*n).Aggregate((tot, n) => tot + n);
```

Comment: I would not define "a simple calculation" something using LINQ. At least not for a (pre)beginner level :P

Comment: you're probably right. It's easy to forget what starting out was like.